# java spring multithreaded environment realization

Tags: java, spring

I am looking for a spring or java library that may implement the following:

When a special event comes, a separate thread should start. This thread should be running for entire session of messaging process. It should handle timeouts, etc.Also it should be responsible for accepting and producing messages to rabbitmq. So for example:

1. message comes
2. Thread should wait for 3 secs before going to answer.
3. If message of type A, it should wait 10 secs.
4. If there's no message for 5 mins, it should generate a special event in rabbitmq.

[image: The description in here]

How to implement it in existing libraries and not to do it hand-made? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want this rather than using the existing `@MessageListener` behavior?

Comment: Because I need to start a long-lived thread for session. So, if my rabbit consumer is able to handle 20 concurrent consumers, it will start 20 long-lived blocking threads, and will not work until at least one of them dies.

Comment: No, **why** do you think you need a long-lived thread?

Comment: because I need timeouts. Session starts, in 10 mins it should be marked as idle and special event should be generated. How to wait for 10 mins? I think I can do a quartz job and check db every second, but I am afraid to do that. Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.